# How to remove unused view from Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp

I have a RCP application with a set of my views and i needn't such views as Debug/* views or Team/* views. How can i remove them from Window->SHow view->Other dialog?

I found here a solution with visibleWhen attribute, but i need to disable not mine items.

Could anyone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ensure that unwanted views do not appear, is to remove the contributing plugins from your RCP app.  Presumably, if you don't want the debug view to appear, then you don't need any debug.ui functionality.  So, it seems to me that you should be removing that plugin from your app.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew is correct, if you don't need the extra view, you can just remove the plugin that contributes the view.
On the other hand, if you need the view but don't want it to be readily available from the UI, you can also use the concept of activities to selectively hide any ui contributions.

please see http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/ for details on how to use them